# Color single pixel in XNA

Tags: c#, xna

Give a Coordinate, how can I color a single pixel in XNA? i.e.

`Coordinate(10,11).Color = Color.Red`

Comment: Do you mean given a single point, how do I render a single pixel based on that point with a specified colour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're planning on doing a lot of pixels, for something like a particle system, it would be better to use a shader. You'll probably run into performance issues eventually just using a SpriteBatch.

Answer (score 2):

There's two ways depending on what coordinates you mean:

For screen coordinates the easiest way is to have a `Texture2D` that holds nothing but a single white pixel, then drawing it with `SpriteBatch` and passing whatever color you want to the `Draw` method.

For 3D space coordinates you want to use a [PointList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb196414.aspx#ID4EWC).

There's a bit more complicated things you could do as well: use `Texture2D.SetData` to make your own single white pixel texture at run time. Or, it's also possible to use a `PointList` and project to screen space.